# How to load a partial model with saved weights in pytorch

Tags: python, pytorch, transfer-learning

I have trained a model on some images in Pytorch. After training I saved the weights of the model. The code for my model is as follows:

My custom model based on ImageClassificationBase class ->

```
import torch
import torch.nn as nn

# Define the new model with the same architecture as the trained model

class NewModel(nn.Module):
    def __init__(self):
        super(NewModel, self).__init__()
        self.conv1 = nn.Conv2d(3, 64, kernel_size=3)
        self.conv2 = nn.Conv2d(64, 128, kernel_size=3)
        self.fc1 = nn.Linear(128 * 30 * 30, 512)
        self.fc2 = nn.Linear(512, 10)

    def forward(self, x):
        x = self.conv1(x)
        x = self.conv2(x)
        x = x.view(-1, 128 * 30 * 30)
        x = self.fc1(x)
        x = self.fc2(x)
        return x
```

Now I want to transfer these weights to a new model which has the same structure before; But I only want to use the weights till the flattening operation; after that I want to re-train the Linear layers based on my new task.

**My attemmpt:**

```
# Load the saved weights from the trained model
trained_model_path = "/content/model_weights.pth"
trained_model_state_dict = torch.load(trained_model_path)

# Create the new model
new_model = Classifier_model()

# Remove the keys corresponding to the layers that you don't want to initialize
new_model_state_dict = new_model.state_dict()
for key in list(new_model_state_dict.keys()):
    if key.startswith('fc'):
         new_model_state_dict[key]

# Update the state dictionary with the learned weights
trained_model_state_dict.update(new_model_state_dict)

new_model.load_state_dict(trained_model_state_dict)
```

But this is showing up error as I am not able just deleting the weights corresponding to fc layers, while I need to replace them with a random number.

Can someone suggest me how to do that?

Answer (score 0):

You can simply load the state dictionary of your trained model and pop the keys which start with `'fc'`:

```
>>> trained = torch.load('model.pth')
>>> trained_trim = {k:v for k, v in trained.items() if not k.startswith('fc')}
```

You can then proceed with loading this partial state dictionary on a newly initialized model using [`load_state_dict`](https://pytorch.org/docs/stable/generated/torch.nn.Module.html?highlight=load_state_dict#torch.nn.Module.load_state_dict) with the strict argument set to `False`:

```
>>> model = NewModel()
>>> model.load_state_dict(trained_trim , strict=False)
```

It will not throw an error for the missing keys but instead provide a list of missing and unexpect keys.

```
_IncompatibleKeys(
   missing_keys=['fc1.weight', 'fc1.bias', 'fc2.weight', 'fc2.bias'], 
   unexpected_keys=[])
```